# How to allow DELETE request in the list-view of Django REST framework ? Is it possible?

Tags: django, rest, http, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to delete List of objects from Django rest framework list-view ? I am passing list of ids of objects [1,2] in delete request and its showing

{u'detail': u'Method "DELETE" not allowed.'}.

Allowed methods at List-view are :GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

I want to add DELETE to this allowed reuqest.

Comment: Add your view code.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Django Rest Framework does not support bulk operations.

You will have to write some custom code for that. There is the third party package [Django REST framework bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk) which might be a good starting point.