# Is it possible to make a PUT request on list view, using ModelViewSets?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My goal is to handle a `PUT` request that contains multiple jsons. In simple words, I just want to be able to update multiple items with 1 `PUT` request. I tried to override the `update()` method in my `ModeViewSet`, but as I saw in my tests, the following request:

```
(example) response = self.client.put('/collections/', [{'id':1, ...}, {'id':2, ...}])
```

didn't even go into the update method's code. Instead, it returned a 'method not allowed' error. I looked for this issue and I found out that, by default, drf supports `PUT` requests only on detail views.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260153/how-to-allow-delete-request-in-the-list-view-of-django-rest-framework-is-it-po) answer here on stack overflow, but I would prefer to see if it can be done without using a 3rd-party package.

- So, is there a proper solution without using a 3rd party package?
- Is it possible to make it work using ModelViewSets or should I use something different?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both of your questions.

What you need is to alter the routers so that they map the PUT verb to some `ViewSet`'s method.

You'll have to copy&paste the route definitions from the [default router](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/2c9c0f1b7f24e2fbedacbb85e6b56eb244a2353c/rest_framework/routers.py#L129-L132) and alter the mapping as - for example:

```
mapping={
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create',
    'put': 'list_update',
},
```